# SQL Server 2008 SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table with lots of columns. One of the columns is `AppointmentNo`, and this column can be either 1 or 2 (basically it is either a first appointment or followup).

Some of the columns include

**tblAppoints**:

```
ClientID
ClientFirstName
ClientLastName
ClientAddress
ClientAppointmentNo
```

I'm trying to select `clientID`'s from this table, however, I don't want to see any clients where the `ClientAppointmentNo = 2`. So only show clients that have `AppointmentNo = 1`, no clients with `ClientAppointmentNo = 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method, using aggregation:

```
select a.clientId
from tblAppoints a
group by a.clientId
having max(ClientAppointmentNo) = 1;
```

If you want to see the appointment details, then one method uses window functions:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             max(ClientAppointmentNo) over (partition by a.clientId) as maxcan
      from tblAppoints a
    ) a
where maxcan = 1;
```